# Regarding Table Entity in Azure table storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I am using Java language and created a class which extends from TableServiceEntity.

```
public class GameLogsByHandGameId extends TableServiceEntity{

    private final String TABLE_NAME = "GameLogsByHandGameId";

    public GameLogsByHandGameId(String handId, String gameId) {
        this.partitionKey = handId;
        this.rowKey = gameId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPartitionKey() {
        return this.partitionKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRowKey() {
        return this.rowKey;
    }

    public long getTableId() {
        return tableId;
    }

    public void setTableId(long tableId) {
        this.tableId = tableId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return TABLE_NAME;
    }
```

Any azure table entity has three system properties, PartitionKey,RowKey and Timestamp.

MSDN Documentation(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) says "The server manages the value of Timestamp, which cannot be modified"

I do not have TimeStamp property in my entity; I though server would anyways insert it in table for every entity.

Though When I see my entity on Table storage; I do not see TimeStamp column?

[image]

Do I need to enable it or something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to enable this property. It is there by default. If you look at `TableServiceEntity` documentation at http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/TableServiceEntity.html. You will see this property. It is called `timeStamp` in Java SDK.

`Timestamp` attribute is set by Azure Table Service when an entity is either created or updated. It denotes the date/time value in UTC when the entity was created/last updated.

As to why this column in not visible, it could be possible that the tool you're using chooses not to display this property. Could you try using other tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is a offical article that list each Azure Storage explorer, include these provided from Microsoft and thirt-party providers, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-explorers/.

As @GauravMantri said, please try using other tools listed in the article.

Comment: @user1955255 You can try VS 2013 or higher server explorer window which list azure resources in it, or else a new client from Microsoft "storage explorer" http://storageexplorer.com/ , or else "cloud explorer" extension for VS 2013/2015 (make sure you check the Azure SDK version supported) https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3896fc2-109b-4420-9c38-b6ab1cfa9fe5